# How to include dependencies for TypeScript Azure Function

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions

I've exhausted the Azure Function documentation and cannot figure out how to deploy a TypeScript Azure Function and include the Node.js dependencies. I'm using VSCode Azure Functions tool to deploy my serverless code on a Linux server.

I cannot use the Kudu service as it is only available for Windows Azure Functions

I've tried including a package.json in both the root directory of my Azure Function app and the literal function folder itself.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is few things.

1. Create project using func tools `func init --worker-runtime typescript`
2. Install typings module [@azure/functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/functions) - if not installed
3. Build project `npm run build:production`
4. If you want you can even publish using `func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>`

To use types

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
```

You can check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#typescript)

Comment: The package.json that VSCode created for me does not include npm run build:production

Comment: @etarrowo https://github.com/mhoeger/typescript-azure-functions/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Yeah this is the command VSCode executes. The npm module is still not being included in the deployment

Comment: to instll modules you must run npm install

Comment: Yes but how? I can't access the Kuda terminal to run npm install after I deploy.

Comment: Well i am lost. Fter you build dist folder should have ready to go versio . You dont need to do anything extra

Comment: Try to run step 3 and 4 i rote

Comment: @etarrowo what you need to is to build and deploy "compiled" version which includes everything. So you wont need to install packages

Comment: I think my issue is that I was using Linux instead of Windows. I deployed the example you shared with you me instantly with Windows and it worked -- I'm now deploying my project using Windows instead to see if it works. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: It doesn't matter if its windows or linux. If you get erros please add them to your question otherwise I am not sure what is your problem